# Setting permissions via drush make; auto-copy settings.php?

Tags: drush

I'm using drush make to build out an installation profile, and it's working great, however, settings.php doesn't get created and files has the wrong permissions.

Is there any way to automate this further by creating settings.php and chmod'ing files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `drush make site.make` you can pass database urls and the site-name as well, and admin credentials.

You have a permissions issue with your webroot and/or drush configuration to not have drupal makes these files for you properly.

Typically when you call drush from the command line you want to do so as your ssh or terminal user -- assure you have proper permissions or are a member of the correct groups (eg, `www-data` if under Linux and using Apache configured thusly).

If for instance you call drupal cron via drush using `drush cron` from a crontab entry; then in that case you usually want drush to run as the webserver user.

In short -- check your permissions, because they sound wonky.

Comment: It's probably this, now that I've looked at it. While I was a member of www-data, I've tried making that my primary group (Before was "sudo" for some reason) and will try drush make again after I logout and -in again.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you go through all the options available at `drush help make` . This option should help you :

> --prepare-install   Prepare the built site for installation. Generate a properly permissioned settings.php and files directory.

Comment: I think this is closest to what I'm wanting.

Answer (score 2):

To set permissions after `drush make`, see http://drupal.org/node/990812.  The most recent patch if functional, but a new simplified version is in the works (same thing, fewer options), and will be committed when ready.

There is also a bash script to set permissions available at http://drupal.org/node/244924

Comment: The bash script that @greg_1_anderson mentions is good.  Just read through the whole page carefully, and look at what the script is doing.  It assumes a group-based permission scheme that may not work for all organizations.